# Product URL not changing

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, magento-1.9.2.1

I have tried updating the url on a product, but it's not changing.

I have tried disabling plugins, clearing cache, sessions etc but still no avail.

Magento 1.9.2.1 CE

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do the re-indexation and try again.

Comment: I tried that too, that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment at this time. How did you try to change the product URL?

> 1. Did you add a product URL key in Catalog > Manage Products > specific product > General tab > Url Key ?
> 2. Did you use URL Rewrite Management?

Comment: I did yeah, that's what isn't updating. We are using Web Server Rewrites.

Comment: sorry, to change it I did 1. By doing it in the product options